# How to use executor.map function in python on keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across a scenario where i need to run the function parallely for a list of values in python. I learnt executor.map from `concurrent.futures` will do the job. And I was able to parallelize the function using the below syntax `executor.map(func,[values])`.

But now, I came across the same scenario (i.e the function has to run parallely), but then the function signature is different from the previous and its given below.

```
  def func(search_id,**kwargs):
      # somecode
      return list

  container = []
  with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
       container.extend(executor.map(func, (searchid,sitesearch=site),[list of sites]))
```

I don't know how to achieve the above.  Can someone guide me please?

Comment: [`**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs) is just a way to take optional named input. If you don't have any specific keyword args to pass in, just don't pass it in. Otherwise, `kwargs` should be a dictionary

Comment: Are there any arguments that get passed as kwargs that are required?

Comment: @sshashank124, I have updated specific arguments . Can you look at it please.

Comment: @IainShelvington. You meant to ask are they any arguments in kwargs which are required ?.  Yes, I have updated the question.

Comment: Look at the following question for details on how to pass a kwargs dictionary as an argument: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs

Comment: what are you trying to parallelize? `executor.map(func, iterable)` will apply the function to each item in the iterable. So I am not sure that is what you want.

Comment: Where is your iterable of values to pass to `map`?

Comment: @IainShelvington. Sorry I will update the question.

Comment: @abhilb, Apologies for incomplete question. I beg your pardon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an iterable of `sites` that you want to `map` and you want to pass the same `search_term` and `pages` argument to each call. You can use `zip` to create an iterable that returns tuples of 3 elements where the first is your list of sites and the 2nd and 3rd are the other parameters just repeating using `itertools.repeat`

```
def func(site, search_term, pages):
    ...

from functools import partial
from itertools import repeat
executor.map(func, zip(sites, repeat(search_term), repeat(pages)))
```

Comment: What if sitesearch is different ? I mean , can the below be done  
executor.map(partial(func, pages=10), search_ids,sitesearch)

Comment: What is `sitesearch`? Is it a list of sites? How does each element relate to the elements in `search_ids`?

Comment: I have list of sites. Now i pass the search term and a site from list of sites to that function. site is basically the url. So, i pass a search term and a url from the list of urls to that function.

Comment: Okay, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Where is this search term coming from?

Comment: To make it clear. Let say i want to search for term tourism in sites google,facebook and twitter, previously what i was doing was calling the function and passing the search term which is tourism and the site google.com and get the result. Again i  call the function with same search term for site facebook and for site twitter as well

Comment: So you want to map the function method with the same search_term and pages parameters but with an interable of sites?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Finally you understood

Comment: @s326280 no problem, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful way of using kwargs in `executor.map`, by simply using a `lambda` function to pass the kwargs with the `**kwargs` notation:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    ....
 
items = [
    { 'arg1': 0, 'arg2': 3 },
    { 'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 4 },
    { 'arg1': 2, 'arg2': 5 }
]

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    result = executor.map(
        lambda kwargs: func(**kwargs), items)
```

I found this also useful when using Pandas DataFrames by creating the items with `to_dict` by typing `items = df.to_dict(orient='records')` or loading data from JSON files.